# Python: How to format the date column of multiple dataframes in a single loop

Tags: python, pandas

In Python I have 5 different dataframes: `stock_df, ltb_df, stb_df, gld_df, comms_df`

I'd like to format the `'Date'` column of all 5 dataframes in a **single loop** instead of typing them out 1-by-1 in the code below. How do I go about?

```
import pandas as pd

stock_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(stock_df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')\
                .apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
ltb_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(ltb_df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')\
                .apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
stb_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(stb_df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')\
                .apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
gld_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(gld_df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')\
                .apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
comms_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(comms_df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')\
                .apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use directly use [`Series.dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) instead of using `apply` method.

Use:

```
dfs = [stock_df, ltb_df, stb_df, gld_df, comms_df]
for df in dfs:
    df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: possible to do this as a list comprehension?

Comment: @spidermarn I think no, and its better not to use list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
import pandas as pd

for df in [stock_df, ltb_df, stb_df, gld_df, comms_df ]:
     df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')\
                .apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```